# Gröbner basis via integer programming

Tags: computational-complexity, computer-science, integer-programming, groebner-bases

I have studied some papers related to solving integer programs via Gröbner bases. I wonder if the other way is possible or not — i.e., given any ideal, can we find the Gröbner basis by translating this into an integer program and then solving it by the usual branch & bound method?

The professor teaching the course has told me to think about it, but I have no clue. Any suggessions?

Comment: Not a coursework. Winter project. It's half done, answers to this question will help me a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ILP is $NP$-complete, while computing a Grobner Basis is $EXPSPACE$-complete. As one has the containments $NP\subseteq PSPACE\subsetneq EXPSPACE$, one should expect that you can reduce ILP to computing a Grobner basis, but not the other direction.

Comment: I don't know about NP complete. Could you please suggest me or give me the link of  any article/book related to this? I will be thankful to you.

Comment: @anjansamanta A reduction is covered on the first page of [this set of notes](https://cims.nyu.edu/~regev/teaching/lattices_fall_2004/ln/integer_programming.pdf).

Comment: Thanks. And from where you have concluded Grobner basis is EXPSPACE complete and the containment relation?

Comment: I haven't read [this article](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=236900) (and am off campus so cannot quickly review it), but others source it for the EXPSPACE complete claim. The containment $PSPACE\subsetneq EXPSPACE$ follows from the [space hierarchy theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_hierarchy_theorem). It is worth mentioning the above reasoning only holds as you phrase the question as "Given *any* ideal, represent it as an ILP". Grobner Basis are very difficult to compute in the *worst case*, but are known to be more manageable than one might expect in particular cases...

Comment: I am no expert in the area, and have only seen this vaguely alluded to (see the second paragraph of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1312.1655.pdf), for example). The situation seems similar to 3SAT being NP-hard but often solvable in practice. That being said, you can't hope for some standard reduction from Grobner Basis computations to ILP due to the reasoning I gave above.

Comment: I am having trouble understand the fact why NP subset of EXPSPACE imples we can't solve grobner basis via integer programming. So actually what we have to do is convert grobner basis to some integer programming first then solve it and again do conversion. Now ILP is NP complete so it can be solved in polynomial time, and the conversion I don't know which category it belongs.So why have you concluded this procedure is impossible?

Comment: If one could reduce grobner basis to an ILP instance (say, via a polynomial time reduction), it would give a reduction from $EXPSPACE\leq NP$, which would show the containment $EXPSPACE\subseteq NP$. As $NP\subset EXPSPACE$ is trivial, and $NP \neq EXPSPACE$ due to the space hierarchy theorem, it follows that such a reduction cannot exist.

From your comment it appears you're quite unfamiliar with complexity theory ("ILP is NP complete so can be solved in polynomial time" is unfortunately quite wrong). I would suggest trying to learn the basics as a way to better understand this argument.

Comment: Yeah I will try my best. thanks:-)